# Hide pdf and .mp4 files in Android

Tags: android, file

I'm developing an app that downloads .pdf and .mp4 files from a server. I'm saving this files on my SD card.

I need to hide these files to only be visible from my app.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Best regards.

Comment: You cannot limit file visibility on SD card.  If you need to keep these files private to your app, then consider using [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use internal storage.  files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them. When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder with a folder name starting with '.' (dot) and save files in this folder,it usually works on all linux versions and android

Comment: How to hide the pdf within this .folder? The problem is the folder is not visible but if we search by file name I am able to see the pdf and even  delete it.

Comment: If you are trying via code, Create a `File` object in the absolute path and call `delete()` function from it,Or if it is from a file manager. There will be a "Show/hide files" or "Show/Hide system files" option. then the folder will be visible

Answer (score 0):

Create folder like this

```
File rootPath = getBaseContext().getDir("Yourfoldername", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!rootPath.isFile()) {
        rootPath.mkdir();
    }

File file = new File(rootPath,  "sample.pdf");
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a folder and Inside folder save your file with '.' before File name and save files, it will work on all versions of android